# Java Getting a link of a product on Ebay/Amazon using JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to make a program that goes to Ebay and get all the titles, prices and link of listings of an item I choose. For example I might look at Iphone 11 prices and my program should give me a list of all the listings in price order and then the link next to each listing. But I can't seem to find out how to get the link of the listing.

**My code:**

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static int[] addX(int n, int arr[], int x)
    {
        int i;

        // create a new array of size n+1
        int newarr[] = new int[n + 1];

        // insert the elements from
        // the old array into the new array
        // insert all elements till n
        // then insert x at n+1
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            newarr[i] = arr[i];

        newarr[n] = x;

        return newarr;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String url =
                "https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=iphone+11&LH_BIN=1&Model=Apple%2520iPhone%252011&_dcat=9355&rt=nc&LH_ItemCondition=3000";
        ArrayList<Integer> itemPrice = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> itemTitle = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> itemLink = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            for (Element row : document.select("li.s-item--watch-at-corner")) {
                final String itemTitle2 = row.select(".clearfix.s-item__wrapper > .clearfix.s-item__info > .s-item__link > .s-item__title").text();
                final String itemLink2 = 'HELP HERE';
                final String tempItemPrice = row.select("div.s-item__detail--primary.s-item__detail:nth-of-type(1) > .s-item__price").text();
                final String fixTempItemPrice = tempItemPrice.replaceAll("[£ ,]", "");
                double doubleItemPrice = Double.parseDouble(fixTempItemPrice);
                int intItemPrice = (int)doubleItemPrice;
                itemPrice.add(intItemPrice);
                itemTitle.add(itemTitle2);
                itemLink.add(itemLink2);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemTitle.size(); i++) map.put(itemTitle.get(i), itemPrice.get(i));
        Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue()).forEachOrdered(e -> sortedMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
        for (String key : sortedMap.keySet()) System.out.println("ITEM: " + key + " PRICE: £" + sortedMap.get(key));

        System.out.println(itemLink.get(1));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
final String itemLink2 = row.select("div.s-item__info > a").attr("href");
```

Comment: @Ajr270 If this answer helps you, consider accepting it by clicking on the V sign next to it.